# How do I execute a function using Qtoolbar buttons?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have tried triggered, actionTriggered and many more and yet it always throws an attribute error, like 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'actionTriggered'. I use a .UI file that i created in QTDesigner.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QToolBar, QAction
from PyQt5 import uic
import sys

class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("TTTT.ui",self)
        self.show()
        self.tbar=self.findChild(QToolBar,"actionfff")
        self.tbar.actionTriggered.connect(self.T)
    def T(self):
        print("mmmmm")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
UIWindow = UI()
app.exec_()
```

It's a test program, because I thought I messed up  in the original code.
Any help will be mutch appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to use `findChild` with uic. The attributes are automatically created using the object name. Note that if `actionfff` is the action, `findChild` won't obviously work, because you need to use the object name of the *toolbar*.

Comment: To connect to the toolbar, you can do `self.toolBar.actionTriggered.connect(self.T)` (of course, if you renamed the toolbar in Qt Designer, you must replace `toolBar` with that name). To connect to the action, do `self.actionfff.triggered.connect(self.T)`. Do not ever use `findChild` to access the widgets from Qt Designer.